# What is a good way to represent a vector in a RESTful url

Tags: url, rest

For a game I'm building I want to PUT tokens to a certain location on the board. The locations on the board are represented by 2D vectors, but now I'm scratching my head over the trivial problem of representing these vectors in the url.

I can think of several schemes, none of which are particularly pleasing:

1. `/point/{x}/{y}` ex. `/point/10/3`
2. `/point/{y}/{x}` ex. `/point/3/10`
3. `/point/({x},{y})` ex. `/point/(10,3)`

The problem with the first two is that it is rather arbitrary which part of the vector comes first. The third one seems risky; I can imagine that's going to be funny to debug because some user agents might encode the '(', ')' or ',' characters, although I expect my server side framework to be tolerant to that.

Have you tried something similar? Am I missing an obviously superior option?

Comment: You can try /point?x=10&y=3

Comment: yes, but that wouldn't be REST then would it?

Comment: Why not? this doesn't violate REST in any way!!

Comment: well, if I would say that each point is a resource, having the same url for them isn't restful. 'Violate' is a strong word to use with an architecural style. Having the same url represent all possible points doesn't match with my use case semantically I feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing at all unRESTful about the three examples you give:

1. `/point/{x}/{y}` ex. `/point/10/3`
2. `/point/{y}/{x}` ex. `/point/3/10`
3. `/point/({x},{y})` ex. `/point/(10,3)`

However, I would not try to represent every square on the board with it's own URI. Would clients want to GET any square individually, or only GET the whole board? If this were, for example, Checkers, it would require 64 round-trips to the server to get the status of every board square. ***Very*** inefficient! Using a single URI for the whole board means the state of each square has to be a property:

```
PATCH /board
{ "x": "10", "y": "3", "token": "black", .. [other params] .. }
```

or

```
PATCH /board
{ "10,3": "black", .. [other params] .. }
```

Don't forget, you can always `POST` if you can't `PATCH` the board.

You must define which comes first (*x* or *y*) **in your API documentation.** Please don't define *y* as being first :-)

Comment: I like the PATCH suggestion. I'd never use a GET on each point to get the board state. But for a PUT it makes sense to use a more refined URI. So GET /board, PUT /board/(10,3) {token: "black"}

Comment: The benefits of PUT/POST/PATCH is that they mark the request URI as being stale in any caches (e.g. the user's browser or OS cache). Therefore it often makes sense to use the same URI you would later GET. Also, in RESTful designs, a URI represents a resource. Resources should always return a representation of themselves via GET requests. So your URI `/board/(10,3)` would still need to return a response for GET requests to be RESTful.